# Relational operators in Matlab vs Octave

Tags: matlab, octave

This code works perfectly in Octave, but not in Matlab. But why? Is there any workaround? Thanks.

```
a = [0; 5; 10];
b = [3 5 7];

a >= b
```

Octave behavior:

```
 0   0   0
 1   1   0
 1   1   1
```

Matlab behavior:

```
Error using  > 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
```

Comment: It's because Octave does automatic broadcasting, in Matlab you have to  do it yourself. The most efficient method usually `bsxfun`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `bsxfun`:

```
>> bsxfun( @ge, a, b )
 ans =
   0     0     0
   1     1     0
   1     1     1
```

[bsxfun](/questions/tagged/bsxfun) is so much FUN!